# "Unsupported operand type for +: NoneType" when trying to append a character to a string

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I am trying to solve the following question:

The string "PAYPALISHIRING" is written in a zigzag pattern on a given number of rows like this: (you may want to display this pattern in a fixed font for better legibility)

```
P   A   H   N
A P L S I I G
Y   I   R
```

And then read line by line: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"

Write the code that will take a string and make this conversion given a number of rows:

string convert(string s, int numRows);

I have written the following code but I am getting error in the bold line
" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'unicode'"

```
class Solution(object):
    def convert(self, s, numRows):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type numRows: int
        :rtype: str
        """
        if numRows==1:
            return s
        
        templist=[None]*numRows
        ret=" "
        
        curRow=0
        goingDown=0
        for each_char in s:
            if templist[curRow]:
                templist[curRow]=each_char
            else:
                **templist[curRow]=templist[curRow] + each_char**
            if (curRow==numRow-1 or curRow == 0):
                goingDown = not goingDown
            if goingDown:
                curRow=curRow+1
            else:
                curRow=curRow-1
                
        for each_str in templist:
            ret=ret+each_str
        print ret
```

Am I doing something wrong in this. It will be great if someone can point out the problem here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what the input looks like? Seems like the formatting got messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions seem to be reversed in the following lines:

```
        if templist[curRow]:
            templist[curRow]=each_char
        else:
            **templist[curRow]=templist[curRow] + each_char**
```

It should probably read:

```
        if templist[curRow]:
            templist[curRow]=templist[curRow] + each_char
        else:
            templist[curRow]=each_char
```

This ensures that it only appends to the string in `templist[curRow]` if that string already exists (is not `None`), and so avoids the error of adding a string to `None`.

A better way might be to set `templist = [""] * numRows`, i.e. a list of empty strings, then just add to it using `templist[curRow] += each_char`, which will always work because you can add a character to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're doing something wrong.

The line `templist=[None]*numRows` makes your `templist` variable hold a bunch of `None`s. You then proceed to take one of those `None`s, and try to "add" one of them to a string with the statement that you have in bold: `templist[curRow]=templist[curRow] + each_char` (i.e. the righthand side of this assignment evaluates to `None + each_char`).

You can't add a string and a `None` in Python, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'PAHNAPLSIIGYIR'
string = list(string)
rows = []

def make_output(string, num_rows):
    i = 0
    while i < num_rows:
        if i%2 == 0:
            a = []
            while len(a) < 4:
                if len(string)==0:
                    break
                a.append(string.pop(0)) 
            rows.append(a)
        if i%2 != 0:
            a = []
            while len(a) < 7:
                a.append(string.pop(0)) 
            rows.append(a)
        i += 1

    for i in range(len(rows)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            print('   '.join(rows[i]))
        if i%2 != 0:
            print(' '.join(rows[i]))

make_output(string,  3)
```

You can use a function like this, where you designate lengths for even and odd rows, then you can `pop` from your string. Then you can just `print` even and odd rows with proper spacing.

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 solve.py
> P   A   H   N
> A P L S I I G
> Y   I   R
>
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/AtBS$ python3.7 solve.py
> M   M   *   H
> Y A E S V S *
> N   I   A
> ```